How using sshkey in local to build docker image with private repo in nodejs package
I have a private repo which installs by gitlab/ssh in package.json.
I want to use ssh in local to build docker image but fail.
`# Build
FROM node:16-alpine as builder

WORKDIR /app/

COPY . .

RUN apk add --no-cache openssh-client
ARG ssh_prv_key
ARG ssh_pub_key

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
        git \
        openssh-server \
        libmysqlclient-dev

# Authorize SSH Host
RUN mkdir -p /root/.ssh && \
    chmod 0700 /root/.ssh
# See: https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/githubs-ssh-key-fingerprints
# COPY known_hosts  /root/.ssh/known_hosts

# Add the keys and set permissions
COPY /.ssh/id_rsa /root/.ssh/id_rsa
RUN chmod 600 /root/.ssh/id_rsa

RUN apk add git


RUN yarn install && NODE_ENV=production yarn run build

RUN yarn add --arch=arm64 --platform=linuxmusl sharp

CMD ["yarn", "start", "build/index.js"]
`


build image docker fail
from node:16-alpine
